# Using pthread to create a clock

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I would like to create a new thread that  remains in a loop. Something like this:

```
void Clock() {
    double Time = 0;
    while (1) {
        usleep(1000);
        Time = (Time+0.1);
    }
    return;
}
```

I would then like my other existing threads to be able to access the latest clock value and use it. How do I declare the "Time" variable so that it can be accessed by all threads and how would I alter the code above to accommodate that? And also what would i need to do to access it?

Comment: Make it a global variable?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have many different source files, can i declare a global variable in a header file to ensure its able to be used in all of my source files? or is there a different solution

Comment: Just making it a global variable would be begging for a race condition. Make it a static with an accessor function that locks a mutex. Lock the same mutex in your `Clock()` function (just while updating, not while sleeping!).

Comment: You realize that time is going to drift?

Comment: Just use a POSIX timer.

Comment: @FredLarson: I would not recommend using a mutex. That way, reading the clock in another thread can greatly increase clock-drift. I'd *at least* use a lock-free atomic. But obviously using a proper timer would be preferable anyway.

Comment: @EOF: That's great. Just as long as the race condition is prevented somehow. And yes, this isn't a wheel that should be reinvented.

Comment: You either need atomic types or use a mutex.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to obtain the current time, you can do so without a thread. Have a look at [Get the current time in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141960/get-the-current-time-in-c) for example.

If you use a thread, please be aware that threads run independently. Have a look at [Mutex lock threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888027/mutex-lock-threads) for a simple example. You will need to use `pthread_create` to create the thread, and `pthread_mutex` to protect the `Time` variable.

I would recommend you start with that first, and leave atomics to the next time.